# Pandas Groupby issue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Python noob and learning.

Running into an issue when I use the Groupby. If I remove the groupby and print result, it is fine. Not sure what the issue is, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

path1 = "/content/NYC_Jobs_1.csv"
path2 = "/content/NYC_Jobs_2.xlsx"
df1 = pd.read_csv(path1)
df2 = pd.read_excel(path2)

result = df1.merge(df2,on="Job ID",how='outer')
grouped = result.groupby('Job ID')

grouped.to_csv('NYC.csv', index=False)
```

Im having an AttributeError

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-066a0fd6dfcb> in <module>
      9 grouped = result.groupby('Job ID')
     10 
---> 11 grouped.to_csv('NYC.csv', index=False)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    909             return self[attr]
    910 
--> 911         raise AttributeError(
    912             f"'{type(self).__name__}' object has no attribute '{attr}'"
    913         )

AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

Comment: Groupby objects do not have the attribute `to_csv` (both pd.DataFrame, pd.Series do) so you cannot do `result.groupby('Job ID').to_csv(...)` You need to do something to the groupby object like sum or count to return a frame or series.

Comment: You prolly want to `.agg()` aggregate the GroupedBy result.

Comment: It seems you want all IDs together when printing. If so, one way is to `sort_values('ID')` and then do `to_csv`

Comment: Thank you, ```sort_values()``` worked.
Not sure how to use the ```.agg()``` but will look into this.

Comment: To try a basic use of groupby.agg you could use `df.groupby('Job ID').agg(lambda s: list(s))` . This aggregates the various columns in the groups in the form of a list. There is a good introduction in `https://datagy.io/pandas-groupby/`

Comment: Hi @gd6noob - in addition to my answer, [I wrote something to help you and others on your learning journey](https://link.medium.com/8IOyX1xLXvb)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you've run into is that you've not kept clear in your mind the distinction between a `DataFrame` and a `DataFrameGroupBy` object.

If you're new to programming, one thing that may not be clear to you yet is the relationship between classes, objects, attributes, methods, and functions. So the error you got is opaque to you.

Let me translate:

- a **class** represents a 'type of thing', like, say, 'a saucepan'
- an **object** is *a member of* a class; a specific saucepan is an object, whereas the 'idea of a saucepan' is a class
- objects can have **attributes**; a saucepan has a handle with a specific length, but this doesn't have to be the same for all saucepans
- some attributes are not really 'properties' (like the length of the saucepan handle), but rather **methods**, meaning things you can do with the object. For example: 'cook spaghetti'.
- these methods are the same kind of thing as a **function**, but they only make sense in the context of the object they are part of (good luck trying to cook spaghetti with your bare hands)

#### I'll illustrate.

The pandas library provides a *function* called `read_csv`. This function returns a `DataFrame` object. All `DataFrame` objects store data across various attributes representing columns in a table (these are themselves another type of object called a `Series`). The `read_csv` function creates a `DataFrame` that stores data read from a CSV file on disk.

`DataFrame` objects have a method, `merge`, which takes another `DataFrame` as the first argument. This method returns a *third* `DataFrame`, which is an amalgam of the two you started with.

`DataFrame`s have a method `to_csv` which causes the contents of the `DataFrame` to be read out to a CSV file.

`DataFrame`s have a method `groupby` **which returns a `DataFrameGroupBy` object**.

Now, `DataFrameGroupBy` objects *do not* have a method called `to_csv`. I hope that you can now understand the meaning of the error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'to_csv'`.

#### The way forward

The `DataFrameGroupBy` object is easy to confuse with the `DataFrame`. As well as having a similar name and attributes for storing data, `pandas` often takes the approach of having `DataFrame` methods return *new* `DataFrame`s.

Why? This allows *method chaining*:

```py
pd.read_csv("/some/file.csv").merge(df2).some_other_method()...
```

Every `(...)` marks a new `DataFrame` being created. The expression is evaluated left to right:

```py
   pd.read_csv("/some/file.csv").merge(df2).some_other_method()...
-> df1.merge(df2).some_other_method()...
-> df3.some_other_method()...
-> df4...
```

Neat. Neat, but confusing if you aren't keeping track. Especially confusing if, just as you're getting used to it, one of these methods *doesn't* return a `DataFrame` at all, but rather some *other* kind of object.

The purpose of a `DataFrameGroupBy` object is to store groups of data *ready for aggregation*. [They have a variety of methods available to do the aggregation, which you can read about in the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.all.html).

[Here is a tutorial](https://realpython.com/pandas-groupby/) on the way to use `groupby` properly. Some examples would be

```py
count_jobs = result.groupby("Job ID").count()
max_some_column_name = result.groupby("Job ID")["Some Column Name"].max()
```

The first of these directly aggregates the data, the second combines a group with another column and finds the maximum value of the other column *for each Job ID*.

In the second case, the output will be a `Series` object. Since such objects *do* have a `to_csv` method, you could successfully write the data:

```py
result.groupby("Job ID")["Some Column Name"].max().to_csv("output.csv")
```